# Yii: Layout for (Nested) Child Module

Tags: layout, module, yii

I've set up a nested module structure in Yii and for some reason the child module doesn't appear to be using any layout at all.

Here is my path heirachy.

```
app
    protected
        modules
            parent
                views
                    layouts
                        column1.php
                        column2.php
                        main.php
                modules
                    child
```

I've added the modules in the config file as follows

```
'modules'=>array(
    'parent'=>array(
        'modules'=>array(
            'child',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Both modules function, but in the child modules all I get is the message explaining the default/index controller can be customized at the following path. No layout content is being displayed.

Based on the documentation, I expected the child module to inherit layout from the parent.

I did generate the child module using gii (which will not create a child module), so I created it as a typical module, added a module folder within my parent, and copied the results into my parent module as a child.

Any ideas where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue lies with the view resolution scheme in Yii. My parent module sets the default layout to 'column1', which is inherited by my child module. Within the 'column1' layout, the 'main' layout is rendered with the following code.

```
$this->beginContent('/layouts/main');
```

In Yii's view resolution scheme, this maps to the layouts folder of the current module. For views in my parent module this maps to the main layout in the parent views folder and works just fine.

`/protected/modules/parent/views/layouts/main.php`

In the case of views in my child module, this maps to the main layout in the child views folder, which doesn't exist, and resolution fails.

`/protected/modules/parent/modules/child/views/layouts/main.php`

A work around, provided on the Yii forum [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/29776-layout-problems-with-nested-modules/), is to modify the 'column1' and 'column2' layouts in the parent modules to use semi-*fixed* paths.

```
$this->beginContent('//../modules/parent/views/layouts/main')
```